# How do I remove "incompatible implicit declaration" warning

Tags: c

> gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.

How do I remove the following warnings (on ubuntu 12.04), without putting all the code in one file?

> hellofunc.c: In function ‘myPrintHelloMake’: hellofunc.c:6:3: warning:
>   incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
>   [enabled by default]

The three files are as follows:

**hellomake.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main() 
{   // call a function in another file   myPrintHelloMake();   
return(0); 
}
```

**hellofunc.c**

```
#include<hellomake.h> 

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {

printf("Hello makefiles!\n");

return;
}
```

**hellomake.h**
    /*
    example include file
    */

```
void myPrintHelloMake(void);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `hellofunc.c` calls `printf` you need to `#include <stdio.h>` there.

If `hellomake.c` calls your `myPrintHelloMake` function, it should `#include "hellomake.h"`

`hellomake.h` should also have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), e.g.

```
#ifndef HELLOMAKE_H_
#define HELLOMAKE_H_

void myPrintHelloMake(void);

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`#inclde<stdio.h>` should be in common header file or seperatly include this in `hellofunc.c`.

Comment: @gpuguy Why wouldn't it? It's obvious to any C programmer, so you must have some serious misconception but it's hard to know what it is.

Comment: it's not good practice including stdio.h in a "common" header file. It means it gets pulled in when it's not needed. header files that exist purely to contain header files are a bit of an anti-pattern